# Text is not being centered on HTML page

Tags: html, css

I have a website at [tactiletimes.org](https://tactiletimes.org/) and the below code does not center the resulting text.

Do let me know if you have any ideas why this is happening. I have already looked at similar questions and they do not solve my problem.

```html
<span style="text-align: center; border:5px; border-radius:10px; font-size:120px; border-style:dotted; border-color:blue">
  <b>The Tactile Times</b>
  <br/>
  <span style="font-size:25px;">A newspaper by young braillists, for young braillists</span>
</span>
```

Comment: @firefields I've sorted it for the OP

Comment: Use div instead of span.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As you can see, I am quite new to CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` are inline elements and do not center by default.

Use a block level element as the wrapper instead.

```html
<div style="text-align: center; border:5px; border-radius:10px; font-size:50px; border-style:dotted; border-color:blue">
  <b>The Tactile Times</b>
  <br/>
  <span style="font-size:25px;">A newspaper by young braillists, for young braillists</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the text is in a span which will be inline by default. you could switch the span to a div or you could set the span to `display:block` like below

```html
<span style="text-align: center; border:5px; border-radius:10px; font-size:6px; border-style:dotted; border-color:blue; display:block;">
  <b>The Tactile Times</b>
  <br/>
  <span style="font-size:25px;">A newspaper by young braillists, for young braillists</span>
</span>
```